# VirtualBox network NAT connect via SSH client

Tags: debian, ssh, virtualbox

I have also used NAT and forwarding and it's working fine (but in my case I want cluster or Jenkins master and Jenkins slave that's why I have created network NAT).

I have created NAT network named NatnetworkLab in VirtualBox and I cannot connect to my machine using ssh client. 
I have already done the port forwarding. My machine have static IP addresses (10.0.2.1 and 10.0.2.2).

ssh between machine1 and machine2 works fine, but I would like use PuTTY to connect to my machines directly from my host machine (Windows 10) using PuTTY.

I have added rules:

- machine 1 127.0.0.1 2222 10.0.2.1 22
- machine 1 127.0.0.1 2223 10.0.2.2 22

I have of course tried to connect via PuTTY using 127.0.0.1 and port 2222 or 2223.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my issue. I have cloned my original debian to create my new Jenkins Slave so I think there is a conflict with may be the original MAC Adress.
When I try to launch and connect with putty on Slave and Master it doesn't work but when one of them is off it's working.

I will post the resolution when I will found where came from the issue

EDIT: It"s working fine with two nodes, so I think I have cloned VM without generated new MAC Adress.